# while installing the npm I'm getting the below error

Tags: node.js, npm, protractor

[image]

**While installing the npm I'm getting the error like below. Please help me. Thanks in Advance.**

[image]

Comment: can you install a newer version of node.js?

Comment: Now I'm using node-v5.3.0-x86.msi

Comment: while installing the protractor it shows the error.                                               gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (E:\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules
\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)

Comment: I will add the screen shot above.

Comment: have you installed `node-gyp` ?

Comment: yes, I already installed node-gyp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [have `git` installed](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#no-git) and directly accessible via `git` command (be on the `PATH`).

Comment: it asks PYTHON to install, how can I install npm without PYTHON. Please help me.

Comment: @rajanasekhar just install Python - it is easy and straightforward: https://www.python.org/downloads/.

Comment: Hi, alecxe, while installing the protractor it gives an error, please check the screenshot added above.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you does not have installed git in your window pc

so Download the git first from link http://git-scm.com/download/win

then install it and try

```
npm install
```

again any error related to permission then try to open your cmd as Run As Admin